# Why does it take R a long time to fit a model with a many-level factor?

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I fit a model with a factor with many levels and it takes R a really long time to fit that model. Why is this?

For example, if I fit a regression to predict players' salaries, and include a factor predictor for all the players' respective nationalities, that would take a longer time than fitting a model for players' salaries with a continuous predictor, like the players' heights.

Comment: It might be helpful to realize that while the factor looks like one variable (it's one column in the data frame, one item in the model specification, etc.), behind the scenes it will actually be treated as a bunch of separate predictors. The model is therefore much more complicated than a model with a single (continuous) predictor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

R is typical - like most statistics packages, it uses QR decomposition for regression.

For fixed $n$, where $p<<n$, just calculating the decomposition itself is effectively quadratic in $p$ - doubling the number of predictors will multiply calculation time by around 4.

So if you go from $p=2$ (linear regression) to say $p=50$, you'd expect it to take something in the region of 600 times longer (in actuality probably somewhat less, for a variety of reasons).

So adding a lot of predictors will mean a substantially longer wait.

Answer (score 8):

That's because with a factor having $k$ levels, R creates $k-1$ indicator variables. So, suppose there are $k=50$ nationalities, you are fitting a multiple regression model with $49$ predictors, compared with a simple linear regression if you treat it as continuous (which you should not). Perhaps you could create a new factor that is the continent or some other coarser grouping of nationalities, so as to speed things up and get a more parsimonious model.